# GoPro.Hero library runs on console application and freezes windows forms

Tags: c#, gopro

I'm trying to control a GoPro Hero 3 camera. I found a library on the Internet: https://github.com/r1pper/GoPro.Hero and from what i read it's a nice library. But when I try to create a connection with the camera my complete windows forms application freezes where my console applications (for test) just makes a connection.
I think it has something to do with the async tasks, what am I doing wrong?

This line creates the connection with the camera and sends a command:

```
var camera = Camera.Create<Hero3Camera>("10.5.5.9");
```

Comment: In what class you are doing this? Maybe initiating a camera from GUI thread makes this problem. Try to do this on another thread.

Comment: Thanks that did the job. I have to put all the commands in a new thread.

Answer (score 5):

You can either call your commands from another thread or simply set HttpRequestMode to sync

```cs
GoPro.Hero.Configuration.CommandRequestMode = GoPro.Hero.Configuration.HttpRequestMode.Sync
```

Description:

`CommandRequest` uses Tasks internally, when we use a blocking method like `Create` instead of `CreateAsync` it calls **Task.Wait** in the method which causes deadlock in UI contexts (using same context as UI thread),by setting `Configuration.CommandRequestMode` to Sync, it uses an alternate method **SendRequestSynchronous** which prevents deadlock.

Comment: Would love to see more description of why this fixes the issue.

Comment: @Gusdor added some description to my answer

Comment: Well, that is horrific!